# Kendo MVVM template for table missing headers

Tags: html, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

I have a table that's bound to a datasource and retrieving data as expected. However, the heading tags are not displaying. What am I missing?

**HTML**

```
<div id="productResults">
<table style="width: 50%" data-bind="source: Products" data-template="productsTemplate">
    <tr>
        <th>Product ID</th>
        <td>Product Name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
<script id="productsTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr>
        <td>#:ProductID#</td>
        <td>#:ProductName#</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift your bindings from `Table` to `tbody` tag like this

try changing for header only

```
<thead>
    <th>Product ID</th>
    <th>Product Name</th>
</thead>
```

OR

```
<table style="width: 50%" >
    <thead>
        <th>Product ID</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="source: Products" data-template="productsTemplate">
    </tbody>
</table>
```